# Android Broadcast Receiver vs Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I am trying to clarify the difference between a Broadcast Receiver and Service in android.

I understand that an activity can start a service by calling `startService` with an intent.

A broadcast receiver can be registered in code or the manifest and can be called with `sendBroadcast`.

**When would you use one vs the other?**

I understand that multiple broadcast receiver's can be listening for the same intent and this is NOT the case with a service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272763/difference-between-services-and-broadcast-receivers?rq=1

Comment: @CommonsWare - They are very related if you think of the question as "which application component should I use for non-user-interactive processing?"

Comment: @Chris - Services themselves don't listen for intents; you usually interact with them via remote method calls. A service _may_ programmatically register a broadcast receiver to watch for intents, though.

Comment: @Chris - wrt number of receivers, I think you may be thinking about using startActivity (which will only result in one activity receiving the intent) vs sendBroadcast (which will result in all matching receivers being sent the intent)

Comment: duplicate, but this thread is better than the main one. more answers and useful solutions

Answer (score 122):

**Services** are meant to perform an action in the background for some period of time, regardless of what the user is doing in foreground (the user could be switching between activities). A good example would be a music player service - the user starts playing music through a music player app but when they exit the app the music keeps playing.

Services are also useful to provide/manage common access to a resource across multiple applications. This is often used for system resources, such as sensors.

**Broadcast receivers** are meant to respond to an intent (usually one sent by a service or a system event), do something, and be done. An example here might be the user touches an NFC-enabled phone to a tag, the system creates an intent for it, and a registered receiver handles it to change some settings (change volume, turn on bluetooth, etc).

When an intent is broadcast via sendBroadcast, it will be sent to *all* receivers that have matching intent filters. However, it is important to note that in API26+ most receivers registered in the manifest are no longer invoked in such situations, see [the Google docs for more information](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-broadcasts.html).

---

Example 1: Suppose you want to expose a function (to be available from any application that wants to use it) that asks a website to calculate degrees of separation from Kevin Bacon.

Note that this example is "do something and return", as opposed to perform a long-running background operation.

You could implement this in several ways:

**Create a library project that all users compile into their application.**

- There are now multiple copies of your code and they could all be different versions.
- You could not batch or cache requests as each request is handled independently.

**Create a broadcast receiver to handle each request.**

- Your application registers a broadcast receiver to accept an Intent asking the Bacon question
- Each application sends an Intent to ask the question.
- The broadcast receiver accepts the Intent and either

  - Passes the request to a service to do the processing, which sends an Intent to the requester with the result
  - Sends a request to the server which will respond using Google Cloud Messaging when it's done
- Because all requests go through one application, you can batch/cache results
- This is always asynchronous
- API is "Intents" - not the friendliest way to expose your functionality

**Create a service to handle each request**

- Your application creates a service to handle the requests, and exposes an API via a Binder or using AIDL
- The API can be synchronous (direct call and return) or asynchronous (allow listener registration and call the listener when the result is ready). You should only choose synchronous if the processing is expected to be very quick; server calls should more often be handled asynchronously
- API is "method calls" - a much friendlier way to expose functionality

---

Example 2: You want to perform some data analysis to find some patterns in your data

**Background Thread** If all processing should happen while the user is in the same application and on the same Activity, a background thread (or better, a coroutine) would be a good approach

**Service** If you want to allow the user to exit the application while the processing is being performed (and notify them of the results later), or allow them to progress through multiple activities in the same application while the processing is being performed, a Service would be a better approach

Comment: Isn't "Create a broadcast receiver to handle each request." not stable because you're making async requests from a broadcast receiver which could be killed?

Comment: @pfrank - Good call - the receiver really needs to either pass it to a service, or send a request to a server that will notify via Google Cloud messaging when it's done. (I've edited the above with this)

Comment: This is one of the best answer I've seen for awhile. Thanks

Comment: ~"common access to a resource across multiple applications".  But BroadcastReceiver can be exported, which will allow it to receive messages from sources outside its application

Comment: @pfrank this is true when not using the 'goAsync' method introduced in API11, if you need to support before this API then you will need to create a service so it's not killed off.

Comment: If we need to perform an AsyncTask in a broadcast receiver (for example, fetching data from firebase at a particular time using AlarmManager), can we start a service from the broadcast receiver?

Comment: @SamudraGanguly Yes. BroadcastReceivers should be short, as they're executed on the UI thread. Note that if you start a service from a BroadcastReceiver and it needs to interact with the UI at certain points, you should broadcast Intents from that service which will be caught by other receivers. If the user has the UI open, you can register BroadcastReceivers in the Activity to catch them.

Answer (score 89):

**Broadcast Receiver**

Quoting [Dianne Hackborn on the Android Developers blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html):

> When handling a broadcast, the application is given a fixed set of time (currently 10 seconds) in which to do its work. 
>   If it doesn't complete in that time, the application is considered to be misbehaving, and its process immediately tossed into the background state to be killed for memory if needed.

Broadcast receivers are limited by maximum amount of time(10 seconds generally), they have to finish.

**Service**

If your action takes some longer time (connecting to the internet can take some).More preferrably as the run at background. You definitely should call a service from the receiver or Activity for this purpose. They are last to be killed by android Operating System.

Conclusion:

1. Generally speaking all the work (fetching, parsing, caching, updating database) which is important to your application should be moved to `Service` as they are long lived on Android. As you've almost considered that all the social networking sites have there `STICKY_SERVICES` which does all troublesome work.
2. `BroadcastReceiver` are mostly used to start the service. It generally depends upon application. Most of the application uses `ConnectivityManager` to broadcast whenever network is UP OR DOWN. With the help of these `Service` are started by `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 6):

First, read the documentation for both [Broadcast Receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

You can find useful tutorials [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).

at last, to make the long story short:

Service starts upon your request (startService(intent)).
You can think of The Broadcast receiver as an intent listener.

Comment: thank you for the links. Great help!

Comment: ~"Service starts upon your request".  Not true for Bound Services, those start automatically.

Comment: The example are clear ~

Comment: The "long story short " conclusion here is not correct to my understanding as a service can be started purely from intents based on intent filters as well.  

  A Broadcast Receiver is a system listener (events from the OS), or listener to other apps.  

  Service is what you use internally in your App.