# Should I use BroadcastReceiver or Service?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I don't clearly understand the difference between them. I tried to read about it and found that Services are for long-running operations but nobody said what about short-running operations.

I want to do something at midnight - just update some things. I've made an AlarmManager for midnight but I don't know if I should call a BroadcastReceiver or a Service.

What should I do?

Comment: What to do?as per requirement you have to used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you will be performing a minimal amount of processing based on what little you have mentioned. In that case a service may be overkill. There are good discussions covering the differences between broadcast receivers and services. Check out the API docs or have a look here:

[Android Broadcast Receiver vs Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548927/android-broadcast-receiver-vs-service)

Comment: I have already found this discussion. Yes, you're right, I need to perform a minimal amount of processing, so I'll use broadcast. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will personally suggest you to use BroadcastReceiver in that case. Because by using the broadcast receiver your application can only be trigerred when the alam goes on. On the other side if you use service then your service will run in background continueously.